# Get count of ids from a table grouped by a some range of values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
-------------------
id    | rating
-------------------
1     | 1.2
-------------------
2     | 1.3
-------------------
3     | 2.3
```

I want a result like

```
rating   row
------------
1        0
2        2
3        1
4        0
5        0
```

as row with rating less than 1 is 0
row with rating greater than 1 and less than 2 is 2
row with rating greater than 2 and less than 3 is 1
row with rating greater than 3 and less than 4 is 0
row with rating greater than 4 and less than 5 is 0

I am totally blank how to make this query
Help me please

Comment: Rating for 1 is 1.2 and it greater than 1 so it should be 2 not 1 as shown in your result!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT table.*, CEIL(rating) AS integer_rating FROM table ORDER BY rating ASC`

[`CEIL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceil) rounds any number larger than `x.0` up to the integer `(x+1)`. The only problem is `0.2` will return `1` and not `0` as you like. But you can do a quick comparison outside of SQL to change to zero.

This will return:

```
id    rating  integer_rating
----------------------------
1    1.2      2
2    1.3      2
3    2.3      3
```

Comment: I have slightly improved this query to get what i want
SELECT count(Q.id), CEIL(rating) AS integer_rating FROM question Q group by integer_rating ORDER BY rating desc;
but the problem is its giving me six row for 0,1,2,3,4,5 i want to merge rating range 0 in one can you suggest

Comment: Thanks for your reply i changed a bit more this query and got what i want here is my final query
SELECT count(Q.id) as cnt, if(CEIL(rating)=0,1,CEIL(rating)) AS rate FROM question Q group by rate ORDER BY rate;

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CEIL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceil) function.

```
SELECT  b.RatingValue, COALESCE(a.IDCOUNT, 0) IDCOUNT
FROM    
        (
            SELECT  CEIL(rating) AS RatingValue,
                   COUNT(*) IDCOUNT
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY CEIL(rating)
            ORDER   BY RatingValue
        ) a 
        RIGHT JOIN
        (
            SELECT 1 RatingValue UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL
            SELECT 5
        ) b     ON a.RatingValue = b.RatingValue
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2dda3/7)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════════════╦═════════╗
║ RATINGVALUE ║ IDCOUNT ║
╠═════════════╬═════════╣
║           1 ║       0 ║
║           2 ║       2 ║
║           3 ║       1 ║
║           4 ║       0 ║
║           5 ║       0 ║
╚═════════════╩═════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks this query really work except one case as default value for rating column is 0 so if rating is zero its missing from the result i want all those rows which have rating 0 should come in rating 1.

Comment: ok, replace `CEIL(rating)` with `IF(rating = 0, 1, CEIL(rating))`. here's the result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3e6a/2